# Run cygwin-compiled c++ programs on linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, compilation, cygwin

I would like to compile a c++ program in cygwin (on windows) and then run it on a Linux machine.. The reason I don't want to just compile it on Linux is missing libraries, and a huge mess (including restricted access) to install these.

I was hoping I could just compile it, then copy the *programname*.exe-file to my linux folder and then run ./*programname*. But that doesn't work. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is: You can't.

Longer answer: You can, but then you have to set up a cross-compiler that generates native Linux binaries. Or use an environment such as [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) in Linux.

The reason you can't just copy an executable file from Windows, even when compiled with GCC, is that the file have a specific format that is not seen as executable on Linux.

Comment: Oh well. I guess I have to dig into the libraries then. Thank you!